# How To: Platform builder for windows CE 6.0

Tags: windows-ce, platform-builder

I am a novice to Platform Builder.

I need to know how to work with platform builder.

As I googled I was not able to find where to start from.

Following is what I am looking for.

1. What exact tools to download? As I searched there is no tool called as platform builder. So what to download.
2. Any books or articles on the same.
3. Walkthrough for using the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to download the [Evaluation Edition of Windows Embedded CE 6.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7E286847-6E06-4A0C-8CAC-CA7D4C09CB56&displaylang=en) (it includes Studio 2005).

Next [download R3](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=BC247D88-DDB6-4D4A-A595-8EEE3556FE46&displaylang=en).

Books are pretty rare.  [Sam Phung has the only one](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-047037733X.html?print=true) that is current.

MSDN has [loads of walk throughs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee504812.aspx).

Be forewarned, it is probably the most complex tool you're ever used (unless you've done embedded OS development before) and it takes a long time to get proficient in it.  I'd highly recommend gettting actual in-person training.

Comment: According to MS you need to install R2 before R3 (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=bc247d88-ddb6-4d4a-a595-8eee3556fe46 look at the required SW)

Comment: The link to the eval edition of Win Embedded CE 6.0 is now removed by Microsoft. You can still find it in Archive.org, but it states you need an activation code. So does this mean the only way to connect to a Win CE 6.0 board is if you can find an old copy of the PB 6 now ?

Comment: The only way to Build a CE 6.0 OS is with PB 6.0.  Connecting to a device for something like app development doesn't require Platform Builder at all.  So it depends on what you mean by "connect"

Answer (score 2):

The best source I found is the video tutorials from Microsoft (by Adeneo)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsembedded/ce/aa731296.aspx

Comment: Link is broken now, I couldn't find the videos - unfortunately MS changed something in it's MSDN structure and seems to be unable to redirect the old links to the new destination

Answer (score 2):

There is a free Exam Preparation Kit from Microsoft that you can download here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsembedded/ce/cc294468.aspx#kit